# How do I get FFMPEG Progress in order to create a progress bar?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyside

I'm trying to create a simple GUI for ffmpeg but am having problems getting the progress of a command. I'm using PySide as the GUI toolkit and I'm also using python3. I'm using QProcess to run the command and would just like to be able to create a progress bar.

EDIT: Preferably I'd like to use QProgressDialog: http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to have a very nice API over a process spawn interface. Moreover, it could be unstable.

Instead, you should be using Python bindings to `libavcodec` and other FFMPEG libraries. There are [plenty of those](http://code.google.com/p/ffvideo/) [on the web](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/).

Comment: Does it matter how updated the bindings are? Also, are they as flexible as using ffmpeg the regular way?